# Connecting Windows 3.1 to Windows SBS 2011 Standard

Tags: windows

How do I get my Windows 3.1 Machine to appear on my new Windows SBS 2011 Standard Server network. I have changed the IP address dns name but I cannot get it to appear I also cannot get it to accept a path/share to another machine running Windows 7 on the network?

Comment: is this a joke?

Comment: Isn't 3.11 the earliest version with networking? Even then, I kinda doubt too many people still have 3.1 machines. What did you have connected to it before?

Comment: You don't Windows 3.1 unlikely has the capabilities to network with post-Windows 95/98 machines.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, to be fair, you can get TCP/IP stacks for DOS. This isn't going to help in the OP's situation, though.

Comment: @BenRichards - I have networked Windows 3.1/95/98 in the past.  I have not attempted to network nor expect it to be even possible to network a NT kernel with a pre-NT-kernel Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I said it because if you can get a TCP/IP stack for DOS, you can network them. At least by tunnelling over the Internet. Though I'd still question why one would do that (at least for anything else than for funzies).

Answer (score 6):

You do not. Not now, not ever.

And don't even think about asking this on ServerFault.

Comment: You geeks dont understand manufacturing machines. I have a laser cutting machine that runs on Windows 3.11 not all machines are running the latest O/S I also have a CAD based infastructure that runs on Windows 7 and a dns sytem that runs Windows SBS 2011 Standard I need to connect all three If you can't help me then say so and dont dis my questions and waste my time.

Comment: @Graham You may stand more of a chance if you defined `connect`. What are you trying to achieve, what do you need the end result to be? Also, sorry for dissing your question, brah. Don't cut me up, yeah?

Comment: Graham. Windows 3.11 was released *ninteen* years ago and support for 3.1 was discontinued in 2002. Have you managed to get this networked before with other, older, networking hardware? Also I work in a school with a number of CAD/CAM machines, including a laser cutter which, remarkably, work(ed) on 98 through to Windows 7.

Comment: We shouldn't waste HIS time! the irony